# How to change the page title for odoo 15?

Tags: python, xml, open-source, erp, odoo-15

I was using this code below to change the title but not working for odoo 15.

```
openerp.your_module_name = function(instance) {
instance.web.WebClient.include({
    init: function(parent, client_options) {
        this._super(parent, client_options);
        this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "Your Title"});
    },
});
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally, I Got the on odoo/addons/web/static/src/webclient/webclient.js
line 37: you can change "*Odoo"* to your required title

```
this.title.setParts({ zopenerp: "Odoo" }); // zopenerp is easy to grep
            useBus(this.env.bus, "ROUTE_CHANGE", this.loadRouterState);
            useBus(this.env.bus, "ACTION_MANAGER:UI-UPDATED", (mode) => {
                if (mode !== "new") {
                    this.el.classList.toggle("o_fullscreen", mode === "fullscreen");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73645445/how-to-change-the-title-of-odoo-in-odoo15-without-editing-the-source-code/73646600#73646600) if you want to change it without editing the original code

Comment: This works well, but it does not work for the login page

Comment: @kamasteve Did you find the solution?